# MySQL WHERE LIKE CONTAINS % IN LAST CHARACTER

Tags: php, mysql

I use this function to exclude possibility to insert new tax with same name:

```
function check_name_free($id, $name) {

if ( $id == "" ) {

    // NEW INSERT

    $sql = "SELECT Name FROM tax WHERE Name LIKE ?";
    try {
        $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
        $rs->execute(array($name));
        $ris = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e);
    }
} else {

    //MODIFY ACTUAL RECORD

    $sql = "SELECT Name FROM tax WHERE Name LIKE ? AND ID != ?";
    try {
        $rs = $db->prepare($sql);
        $rs->execute(array($name, $id));
        $ris = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e);
    }
}

if ( count($ris) > 0 )
    return false;

return true;

}
```

But when, on my form, i'll modify ( `$_POST['action'] == "edit"` ) an existing entry with name with last char %, example **`TAX 20%`**, my script return `false`.

Actual record inside `table tax`:

Name: TAX 10%

Name: TAX 20%

Name: TAX 21%

my index.php

```
if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "edit" ) {
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];

   $free = check_name_free($id, $name);

   if ( !$free ) {
     echo "Name already in use";
     exit();
   }

 // continue edit
}
```

How to modify the `LIKE ?` to accept correct $string with `%` on last char?

Comment: Dont store things like `%` and `TAX` in the colunn in the database. What the database needs is a column with `20` in it so you can use it in calculations. If you want to show the tax rate to users then add the `%` and `TAX as part of your presentation layer

Comment: You can escape a `%` in a LIKE by doing `LIKE 'TAX 21%%'` but you should not be doing that in this case

Comment: I need to include % in my entry. What's the formula to excape % (in final position) when I'm using LIKE?

Comment: I just showed you! In comment 2

Comment: little hint `ID != [number]` is slow better is to use `(ID < [number] AND ID > [number])` because it will trigger a index range scan.

Answer (score 1):

looking to mysql doc  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

you could escape  `%` using `\%`

```
  SELECT 'David%' LIKE 'David\%';
```

or using regexp

```
 select 'mystring%' regexp('%');
```

in your case

```
SELECT Name FROM tax WHERE Name like ('%21\%')
```

or

```
 SELECT Name FROM tax WHERE Name regexp('21%')
```

Comment: OK thanks. But for a general purpose function it still is working? For example if I insert a Name = "TAX 21 PERCENT" still I need to use regexp('TAX 21 PERCENT') ?

Comment: your comment is not clear  ..   what do you mean .? . your question is about  the use of %   as costant  .. and my answer  (i think) clearly answering  to your question  .. the use of regexp  ..and like with escape sequence is for general pourpose.. . ..